# How do I pass an integer from a child widget to the parent widget?

Tags: flutter, parent-child

I'm in the process of making a custom navigation bar for my project, and need to pass the current page # from the child navigation bar widget, to the main page. I can't seem to figure out the best method for transferring the int.

Custom navigation bar with int needed to be accessed:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_app/theme.dart';

class CustomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomNavBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomNavBar> createState() => _CustomNavBarState();
}

class _CustomNavBarState extends State<CustomNavBar> {
  //Need to pass this int to parent
  int currentPage = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
          topRight: Radius.circular(24),
        ),
      ),
      color: primaryColor,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child: navBarItem(0, Icons.home)),
          Expanded(child: navBarItem(1, Icons.looks_one_rounded)),
          Expanded(child: navBarItem(2, Icons.looks_two_rounded)),
          Expanded(child: navBarItem(3, Icons.looks_3_rounded)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget navBarItem(
    int index,
    IconData icon,
  ) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          currentPage = index;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 80,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        child: Icon(
          icon,
          color: index == currentPage ? Colors.white : primaryAccentColor,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Main.dart where int is needed to be accessed:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_app/Pages/home_page.dart';
import 'package:my_app/Pages/profile_page.dart';
import 'package:my_app/Pages/testing_page.dart';
import 'package:my_app/Pages/testing_page2.dart';
import 'package:my_app/widgets/custom_navbar_widget.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: RootPage(),
    );
  }
}

class RootPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const RootPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RootPage> createState() => _RootPageState();
}

class _RootPageState extends State<RootPage> {
  //Replace this int with the one set from CustomNavBar
  int currentPage = 0;

  List<Widget> pages = [
    const HomePage(),
    const ProfilePage(),
    const TestingPage(),
    const TestingPage2(),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      top: false,
      child: Scaffold(
        extendBody: true,
        body: pages[currentPage],
        bottomNavigationBar: CustomNavBar(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Function`?

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak I'm very new to coding in a software context so forgive me if I'm not bright. I'm unaware of the way you imply for me to use 'function' to transmit an integer between files.

Comment: @ChaseB. Are both classes in the _same_ file? If so, one option would be to create it as a _global_ variable.

Comment: @MendelG I've seen global variables as an option but have seen people mentioning that as the project grows how they're difficult to keep track of. Part of my goal too is to keep the widget self contained as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `ValueChange`. Actually, this is a signature for callbacks that report that an underlying value has changed.

Look at the implementation :

```dart
typedef ValueChanged<T> = void Function(T value);
```

Also, you can use it in the child class like this :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_app/theme.dart';

class CustomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomNavBar({Key? key, required this.onItemSelect}) : super(key: key);

  final ValueChanged<int> onItemSelect;

  @override
  State<CustomNavBar> createState() => _CustomNavBarState();
}

class _CustomNavBarState extends State<CustomNavBar> {
  //Need to pass this int to parent
  int currentPage = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
          topRight: Radius.circular(24),
        ),
      ),
      color: primaryColor,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child: navBarItem(0, Icons.home)),
          Expanded(child: navBarItem(1, Icons.looks_one_rounded)),
          Expanded(child: navBarItem(2, Icons.looks_two_rounded)),
          Expanded(child: navBarItem(3, Icons.looks_3_rounded)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget navBarItem(
    int index,
    IconData icon,
  ) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          widget.onItemSelect(currentPage);
          currentPage = index;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 80,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        child: Icon(
          icon,
          color: index == currentPage ? Colors.white : primaryAccentColor,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And check for new changes in parent, like this :

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: RootPage(),
    );
  }
}

class RootPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const RootPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RootPage> createState() => _RootPageState();
}

class _RootPageState extends State<RootPage> {
  //Replace this int with the one set from CustomNavBar
  int currentPage = 0;

  List<Widget> pages = [
    const HomePage(),
    const ProfilePage(),
    const TestingPage(),
    const TestingPage2(),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      top: false,
      child: Scaffold(
        extendBody: true,
        body: pages[currentPage],
        bottomNavigationBar: CustomNavBar(onItemSelect: (value) => print(value),),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For more detail, please check :
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueChanged.html